# Using SSL with IIS

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, private-key

I have .crt file and .key file and I want to use SSL for my web application. I have tried with option "Complete Certificate Request" to import certificate in IIS, but it show certificate imported and actually it is, but when I edit binding, it won't display in selection in IIS.

My certificate does not have private key, I have it separately, in a .key file.

Can you help me to fix this? Is there any way to combine key and certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make p12 (pfx) file from .key and .crt. You can use openssl do make it.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -name "friendlyname_for_certificate"
```

Then import certificate.pfx into LocalMachine\My store. It should be available in IIS.

Comment: Thank you, I figured that and used this command, openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.crt -inkey privatekey.key -out mycert.pfx

Answer (score 0):

IIS display certificate in selection if certificate has private but my certificate doesn't contain it and I have it in separate file. So I combined both using OpenSSL given below command. It creates new pfx file and we need to import it in IIS and it display that certificate in selection.

```
    openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.crt -inkey privatekey.key -out mycert.pfx
```